# How to Increase the size of post is that any function to increase the size

Tags: php, ssl, https

When https-SSL encrypts both of this methods, what is the difference in way browser does this. Which parts are encrypted and which are not? I somewhere read, that the destination url is not encrypted in POST, is that true? If it is true and same in GET, where are all the parameters?

Edit2: still dont know the answer on my question. When both methods are encrypted with same data, does the look the same when sniffed? What parts are encrypted and which are not?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12531/ssl-with-get-and-post)

Answer (score 0):

In HTTPS there is an additional layer between HTTP (e.g. POST, GET) and TCP: the SSL encryption. This encryption does not care if the data are GET or POST, they even don't care if it is HTTP at all. This means everything will be encrypted. And because a GET requests with the same parameters looks different to a POST request with the same parameters in HTTP it will also look different in HTTPS. Even more, the same HTTP message will look different between multiple HTTPS requests because every time another encryption key will be used.